# Unsubscribe Nested Observable when outer observable is false

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular13

I am developing some code where as long as a checkbox is true some inputs will calculate some values and modify other inputs so i came to a solution like this

```
// boolean observable
this.toggleObservable.subscribe((value)=>{
 if (value) {
this.dataService.calculateValuesObservable.subscribe(...logic that changes the values reactively)
}
})
```

the problem is when i set the toggle off i cant unsubscribe from `calculateValuesObservable`

any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [switchMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/switchMap) to unsubscribe from the previous subscription and [NEVER](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/const/NEVER) to skip when checkbox is disable

```js
import { NEVER } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.toggleObservable.pipe(
  switchMap((isChecked) => isChecked
    ? this.dataService.calculateValuesObservable
    : NEVER
  ),
).subscribe((value) => {
  console.log(value);
})
```

Comment: Amazing! thanks for the solution, just one question, I guess the import of EMPTY its just a typo right?

Comment: yes it is a mistake, the first time I used EMPTY but it must NEVER because EMPTY sends a completed event

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```js
this.dataService.calculateValuesObservable.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.toggleObservable), // get the value of toggle
  filter(([toggle, value]) => !!toggle), // only continue with pipe if toggle is true
  map(([toggle, value]) => value)        // transform the result
).subscribe(value => {
   // logic that changes the values reactively
})
```

You subscribe the `calculateValuesObservable` and combine it with the latest value of `toggleObservable`. Afterwards you `filter` by the value of `toggle`.